# How to connect node.js with monogodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to node.js, mongodb.
please suggest me a good tutorial to learn this stuff.
And if any IDE is there for node.js developement ?

Comment: i tried node.js as said in this [link](http://www.celsoft.com/rest-json-html-and-node-js-connect-them-all). Some configurations they said.That one i am able to do in apache. But in IIS, not able to find theway.

Comment: http://codisthan.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/todo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js does not do IDEs really.  Just use a text editor.  I personally like Sublime Text 2.

Look at [mongoosejs.com](http://mongoosejs.com) for a mongo library.

Comment: Thanks. Actually first i tried hello world app in node as explained in this [link](http://www.celsoft.com/rest-json-html-and-node-js-connect-them-all). Some proxy settings they said to configure in server.That one i dont know how to do in IIS.

Comment: In apache it is working.Help me in this.

Comment: Node does not need to use Apache or IIS at all.  It has it's own web server build in.  IIS is just extra baggage you don't need.

Comment: sorry i didn't explain the problem clearly.Problem is in my Html page i want to call the node.js script which is running in a port.for that in javascript if i am using function like this    > $.getJSON('/nodejs/server/messages/1', function(result) {
 debugger;
 var df = result;
      document.getElementById('txtCompanyId').value = result[0]['CompanyID'];
   document.getElementById('txtCompanyName').value = result[2]['CompanyName'];
    });
  }

Comment: that function gives error like cross domain access failed. for that i did some settings in apache. In IIS how to do that ?